# Linux kernel defconfig options not in resulting .config using BuildRoot

Tags: linux, kernel, buildroot

I am building kernel version 2.6.39.4 via BuildRoot for an arm target.

I am using a custom `defconfig` file, into which I added the following 3 options:

```
CONFIG_WIRELESS=y
CONFIG_WEXT_PRIV=y
CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT=y
```

In the resulting `.config` file for the kernel, the only option that I see out of the 3 I added to my `defconfig` is `CONFIG_WIRELESS=y`

Is this normal? I know some kernel config options are "hidden", but will that keep them from showing up in the final `.config` for the kernel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `WEST_PRIV` and `WIRELESS_EXT` are blind options (i.e. they have no prompt, they are not visible in menuconfig/xconfig).
So you cannot simply set their value in a .config (or defconfig) file.
They are only enabled when another option `select`s them.
So you have to enable some relevent option that is visible, which will then automatically `select` `WEXT_PRIV` and `WIRELESS_EXT`.

Comment: Just to clarify: Are there, lets call them "child options", which are invisible until their "parent option" is selected? Basically if I want `WEST_PRIV` or `WIRELESS_EXT` to be present in a config, I need to select their parent option first. Or are you saying there are just options which are always blind options and will never appear in the resulting `.config` for a kernel?

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby  *" Are there, lets call them "child options"..."* -- You're conflating an option that only appears in menuconfig when its "depends on ..." dependency is enabled with the blind option.  ThomasPetazzoni calls it a blind option because it doesn't appear in menuconfig ever.   Your defconfig got pruned, and unnecessary options were deleted because there is no enabled option that selects those blind options.  If you did have an enabled option (that auto selects those blind options), then those blind options would be in the .config file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it by just setting CONFIG_HOSTAP=y. This option causes the following option to be set as well:

```
CONFIG_WIRELESS=y
CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT=y
CONFIG_WEXT_CORE=y
CONFIG_WEXT_PROC=y
CONFIG_WEXT_SPY=y
CONFIG_WEXT_PRIV=y

CONFIG_WLAN=y

CONFIG_LIB80211=y
CONFIG_LIB80211_CRYPT_WEP=y
CONFIG_LIB80211_CRYPT_CCMP=y
CONFIG_LIB80211_CRYPT_TKIP=y
```

I have verified that just setting CONFIG_HOSTAP=y in defconfig does indeed cause the above options to be enabled in .config when using buildroot.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution for some kernel versions :
https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/9/6/787

This patch adds parent that selects the wext_* configs.
later you need to go to your board config ie:
arch/arm/configs/imx_v7_android_defconfig
and add line:
CONFIG_WIRELESS_ALLCONFIG=y

then recompile the kernel , ie: on Android you do:
make -j32 kernelimage